# Syntax error with ternary operator

Tags: python, ternary-operator

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use ternary opertor which has this format (I think so)

```
value_true if <test> else value_false
```

Here's a snippet of code:

```
expanded = set()

while not someExpression:

    continue if currentState in expanded else expanded.push(currentState)

    # some code here
```

But Python doesn't like it and says:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (pointed to if)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ternary operation in python using for *expression*, not *statements*. Expression is something that has value.

Example:

```
result = foo() if condition else (2 + 4)
#        ^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^
#      expression               expression
```

For statements (code blocks such as `continue`, `for`, etc) use `if`:

```
if condition:
     ...do something...
else:
     ...do something else...
```

What you want to do:

```
expanded = set()

while not someExpression:
    if currentState not in expanded: # you use set, so this condition is not really need
         expanded.add(currentState)
         # some code here
```

Comment: break is not equivalent to continue at all

Comment: By the way, `not x in y` = `x not in y`.

Comment: I'm sorry my code misled you a little, I've edited code so you'll understand that I still need continue operator.

Comment: well if that's the case then `print` should not work in ternary operations.

Comment: As I understand, you don't really need to `continue`. Just past "some code" into the `if` block after adding to the `expanded` (see last line of my code).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I don't know what exactly you are referring to, but (1) Python 3.x `print` is a function (call) and hence an expression and (2) Python 2.x `print` can print the result of any expression, including of course conditional expressions.

Comment: @defuz, So from your answer I understood that Python is not good at ternary operator, am I right?

Comment: @megas, Again, for expression: `one if condition else two`. For statements: `if condition: do_something()`.